# Injecting Spring Context into Non-spring Class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm relatively new to Java and coming from a web background I found myself trying to implement a web application in Spring.

The main problem is I have the following folder structure:
[image]

And I am trying to inject Spring context into any class found in the Controllers folder, which basically, as far as I understood means that my classes are not Spring-dependant.

The application uses MongoDB as a backend, and I am trying to instantinate the context like this:

```
WebApplicationContext context = ContextLoader.getCurrentWebApplicationContext();

IODataInterface mongo = context.getBean(BookModel.class);
```

I'm getting this exception on the context.getBean(...) line: com.web.spring.Controllers.DemoController.DemoController(DemoController.java:19)

Any help is appreciated and I'd be really glad if someone could properly explain me the actual terminology as, you might have guessed already, I have jumped into some pretty advanced stuff for someone with 0 Java work experience.

Full exception stack:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

And as far as I see, the context seems to get created, but the getBean() doesn't work. I'm really confused now.

Comment: Post full exception, and your controllers should already be beans, so just normal autowiring should work.

Comment: I've added the exception, not sure about the autowiring, as so far I actually seem to have the context, but the getBean still doesn't work. BookModel is defined in the applicationContext too as a Bean. This is really confusing.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be trying to get an instance of a model class (annotated by `@Document` I imagine, since you're using MongoDb). `@Document` and JPA `@Entity` annotated classes are actually not Spring Beans.

So to instantiate a new one you can just use `new BookModel()`.

PS. as an aside, please adopt a low case package/folder naming convention. Only class names should start with a capital letter.

Comment: My model class also uses a MongoTemplate which I am no longer sure how to initialize without the Bean. What would be the proper approach for this?

Comment: This is not a good design as you're coupling your models with the implementation of the data layer (imagine if you now had to save the objects in something else and not MongoDb). If you're using MongoTemplate, introduce a "service" layer where you inject the MongoTemplate and use it.  Keep your business  logic in the services and inject the services into your controllers. Also you can't get spring to inject your dependencies into model classes.